# OpenCL2 work_group_reduce_add float incorrect output

Tags: c++, c, c++11, c++14, opencl

I'm learning opencl, but in one of my tests I tried to use work_group_reduce_add to add 3 floating values of an array (1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f), the result I expected was 4.5f the most was 4.0f. And when I try a matrix with 2 values (1.5f, 1.0f), the result is the expected 2.5f, but when I try with more values from the third element of the matrix, the floating values start to be treated as integers. My code is just below.

```
std::vector<cl::Platform> plataforms;
cl::Platform::get(&plataforms);
std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
plataforms.front().getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);

cl::Context context(devices.front());

const char* code = "\
    __kernel void test(__global float* a, __global float* b) {\
        b[0] = work_group_reduce_add(a[get_global_id(0)]);\
    }\
";

cl::Program::Sources src(1, std::make_pair(code, strlen(code)));
cl::Program program(context, src);
program.build("-cl-std=CL2.0");
cl::CommandQueue queue_default(context, devices.front(), CL_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE | CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE | CL_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE_DEFAULT);
cl::CommandQueue queue(context, devices.front());

cl::Kernel kernel_test(program, "test");

float a[3] = { 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f };
float b[1] = { 0.0f };

cl::Buffer _a(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float) * 3, a);
cl::Buffer _b(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float), b);

kernel_test.setArg(0, _a);
kernel_test.setArg(1, _b);

queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_test, cl::NDRange(), cl::NDRange(3), cl::NDRange(3));
queue.finish();
```

I also changed the matrix to (1.0f, 1.5f, 4.6f) and changed the code to test work_group_reduce_max () and expected the 4.6f result, but it provided 4.0f =/

```
__kernel void test(__global float* a, __global float* b) {
    float val = a[get_global_id(0)];
    float result = work_group_reduce_max(val);
    b[0] = result;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried only writing the result from one work-item? As it stands, `b[0]` is written to by all work items, which does not have well-defined results. I.e. `float result = work_group_reduce_add(a[get_global_id(0)]); if (get_global_id(0) == 0) b[0] = result;`

Comment: it didn't work = / the result was the same as the other code